# DOS attacks on Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Is that correct that with the execute-order-validate schema on Hyperledger Fabric, it is more sensitive to DOS attacks? As all the endorsing peers process any incoming transaction from the application.

Comment: Not any but the one with valid signature !

Comment: So, if the application has the valid signature to sign the TX, it can DOS the blockchain?

Comment: Yes.. but then as it's a private network admin can revoke access anytime..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the question, as noted in comments, Hyperledger Fabric is a permissioned blockchain platform. This means that the parties that can host nodes and/or transact on the system can be restricted to known identities.

A party that mounts a DOS on the system can have their access revoked, and more importantly, since they are known identities rather than anonymous, can be held to account for their actions (or inaction, in the case they were hacked).